# In Pandemic: on the brink, can I remove multiple bioterrorist cubes at once for a cured strain?

Tags: pandemic, pandemic-on-the-brink

In Pandemic On the brink we ran into a situation where both the black strain and bioterrorist purple strain were cured. At one point one of the players moved into a territory that had multiple black and purple cubes.

My question, is it one action to remove all black and purple cubes because they are both cured or does it require one action each?

Comment: In regular pandemic, after a cure is found, you can use 1 action to remove all cubes of a single color, just like the medic can do normally. It is still 2 actions to remove 2 colors. But don't know if the bioterrorist cubes have special rules.

Comment: It doesn't in the aspect of removing the cubes, they work in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 2 actions, 1 per color. The ability to treat a cured disease is described in the original rules, under the list of actions you can perform:

> Remove 1 disease cube from the city you are in, placing it in the cube 
>   supply next to the board. If this disease color has been cured (see 
>   Discover a Cure below), remove all cubes **of that color** from the city you 
>   are in.

So it is 1 action to remove all cubes "of that color" if that color is cured. Unless On the Brink rules describe a special exception for bio-terrorist cubes, then this still applies.

Comment: This applies in On the Brink as well.  Unless of course the player was the medic, in which case they would treat all the cubes without taking any actions.

Comment: Awesome thank you, this is what we thought but wanted to double check!